How to sum complex exponentials to produce a signal in python
I've got a signal with known shape (from Oppenheim and Willsky problem 3.22a.(b)). I solve for the Fourier coefficients analytically and am happy with their values, given by.
$$ a_0 = 1/2 $$
$$a_k = \frac{6 sin(\frac{\pi}{2}k) sin(\frac{\pi}{6}k)}{\pi^2k^2}$$
also note the period $T = 6$, so $\omega_0 = \frac{\pi}{3}$.
I want to code it up so I can see an approximation of the signal as I use more and more Fourier modes. Here's the python:
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

L = 10
t = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)

x_t = np.zeros(t.shape, dtype=np.complex128)
for k in range(-L, L+1):
    a_k = 0.5 if k == 0 else 6*np.sin(np.pi * k /2) * np.sin(np.pi * k /6) /(np.pi**2 * k**2)
    x_t += (a_k * np.exp(1j + k * np.pi/3 * t))


plt.plot(t, np.real(x_t))
plt.plot(t, np.imag(x_t))
plt.show()


I expect to see something that looks like the original signal, but instead I get this

If I add plt.ylim((-1,3)) to limit the plot to look for the signal where I expect to see it (in case the blow up is just some kind of edge effect), I see only this:

I'm confused. Mathematically, I should be getting back my signal. What is going on?

Note the signal is continuous time, but I believe I should still be able to calculate its values at discrete points this way.

I spotted it! I was adding 1j in the exp, and I need to be multiplying by it.

